# Sliced or hide Checkbox select option

Tags: javascript

I have two select option categories. The first One Strong Subjects and second one is Weak Subject.

All options are same in both category. What i want is after selecting the strong subject, the selected option get removed from weak subject category.

[image]

```js
function strongsubjects(){

var str = document.querySelector(".strong input");

str.style.display="none";


}
```

```html
<div class="strong">
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="strongsubjects()" value="1">1
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="strongsubjects()" value="2">2
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="strongsubjects()" value="3">3
</div>
<div class="weak">
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="weaksubjects()" value="1">1
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="weaksubjects()" value="2">2
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="weaksubjects()" value="3">3
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want I think

```js
    function strongsubjects(obj){
      if(obj.checked){
        document.querySelector(`[data-week-val="${obj.value}"]`).style.display="none";
      }
      else{
        document.querySelector(`[data-week-val="${obj.value}"]`).style.display="block";
      }
    }
    function weaksubjects(obj){
      if(obj.checked){
        document.querySelector(`[data-strong-val="${obj.value}"]`).style.display="none";
      }
      else{
        document.querySelector(`[data-strong-val="${obj.value}"]`).style.display="block";
      }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="strong" style="width:50%;float:left">
    Strong
      <div data-strong-val="1">
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="strongsubjects(this)" value="1">1
      </div>
      <div data-strong-val="2">
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="strongsubjects(this)" value="2">2
      </div>
      <div data-strong-val="3">
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="strongsubjects(this)" value="3">3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="weak" width="50%" style="width:50%;float:left">
    Week
    <div data-week-val="1">

      <input type="checkbox" onclick="weaksubjects(this)" value="1">1
      </div>
      <div data-week-val="2">
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="weaksubjects(this)" value="2">2
      </div>
      <div data-week-val="3">
      <input type="checkbox" data-week-val="3" onclick="weaksubjects(this)" value="3">3
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: One side you will check then second side will be hide and vice versa

Comment: i Want to do in javascript only, not in js framework

Comment: @abhaykumar Okay I have changed to javascript only now. jquery has been removed please check

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you're looking for. The below code loops through all the checked checkboxes in each `.weak` and `.strong` divs, and hides the corresponding checkbox in the other div.

Before hiding the divs, all the previously hidden checkboxes are shown temporarily (in the 1st 2 lines of the function)

```js
function filterOptions(){
  $(".strong input[type='checkbox']").show();
  $(".weak input[type='checkbox']").show();
  
  $(".strong input[type='checkbox']:checked").each( function(){
    $(".weak input[data-subject='" + $(this).attr("data-subject") + "']").hide()
  })
  $(".weak input[type='checkbox']:checked").each( function(){
    $(".strong input[data-subject='" + $(this).attr("data-subject") + "']").hide()
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="strong">
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="filterOptions()" data-subject="1">1
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="filterOptions()" data-subject="2">2
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="filterOptions()" data-subject="3">3
</div>
<div class="weak">
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="filterOptions()" data-subject="1">1
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="filterOptions()" data-subject="2">2
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="filterOptions()" data-subject="3">3
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that the values are sorted as showed in the image. You could reverese the logic for `weaksubjects` function.

```
function strongsubjects(){
        const weakSubject = document.querySelectorAll(".weak input");
        const strongSubject = document.querySelectorAll(".strong input").forEach((el,index) => {
         if (el.checked) {
           weakSubject[index].parentElement.style.display= 'none';
         } else {
           weakSubject[index].parentElement.style.display= 'block';
         }
       });
    }
```

```
 <div class="strong">
     <div><input type="checkbox" onclick="strongsubjects()" value="1">1</div>
     <div><input type="checkbox" onclick="strongsubjects()" value="2">2</div>
     <div><input type="checkbox" onclick="strongsubjects()" value="3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="weak">
      <div><input type="checkbox" onclick="weaksubjects()" value="1">1</div>
      <div><input type="checkbox" onclick="weaksubjects()" value="2">2</div>
     <div><input type="checkbox" onclick="weaksubjects()" value="3">3</div>
</div>
```